# ModSecurity won't apply rules - no error log entries

Tags: centos, mod-security

I have a fresh installation of CentOS 8. I installed Apache 2.4.37 from the repo. Then installed the latest ModSecurity:

```
dnf install mod_security -y
```

Checked the installation

```
dnf info mod_security
```

Result:

```
Name         : mod_security
Version      : 2.9.2
```

The required Apache modules are available / loaded:

```
apachectl -M | grep security -> security2_module (shared)
apachectl -M | grep unique -> unique_id_module (shared)
```

Installed the core rule set from the repo:

```
dnf install mod_security_crs
```

which automatically links the rules into the apache folder

```
/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules
```

Rules have been checked / are at place.

The main config file

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf
```

includes necessary further config files, including the rules conf files themselves:

```
IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf
IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/*.conf
IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/local_rules/*.conf
```

(paths have been double-checked)
and activates the rules engine:

```
SecRuleEngine On
```

The rules config file `modsecurity.d/crs-setup.conf` (which is included in `mod_security.conf`, see above) provides

```
SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,auditlog,deny,status:403"
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,auditlog,deny,status:403"
```

Apache httpd.conf calls ModSecurity:

```
SecStatusEngine On
```

A restart (`apachectl restart`) shows that ModSecurity was loaded successfully:

```
ModSecurity: StatusEngine call successfully sent. <-- including LUA etc.
```

Tests with manipulated URLs like a script insert:

```
/?q=%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E%27
```

show no reaction whatsoever on ModSecurity's side. No entries at all in ModSecuritie's audit and debug log files (debug level was set to 3), no errors in Apache's log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just omitted the inclusion of conf.d directory in the Apache httpd.conf. Thats why the ModSecurity engine could start, but read no rules.

I added the line

```
IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
```

in httpd. conf, and everything runs as expected.